# Thread updating the class object

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How to return a class object from threads or how to persist its state?

```
struct DataStructure
{
    MapSmoother *m1;
    std::vector<Vertex*> v1;
    std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit;

    DataStructure() {
        m1 = NULL;
        v1;
        vit;
    }
};

DWORD WINAPI thread_fun(void* p)
{
        DataStructure *input = (DataStructure*)p;
        for( ; (input->vit) != (input->v1).end(); ){
            Vertex *v = *input->vit++;
                (*(input->m1)).relax(v);
        }
        return 0;
}
main()
{
//Reading srcMesh
//All the vertices in srcMesh will be encoded with color
MapSmoother msmoother(srcMesh,dstMesh); //initial dstMesh will be created with no edge weights 
DataStructure* input = new DataStructure; //struct datatype which holds msmoother object and vector "verList". I am passing this one to thread as a function argument
for(int color = 1; color <= 7 ; color++)
{
        srcMesh.reportVertex(color,verList); //all the vertices in srcMesh with the same color index will be stored in verList datastructure(vector)

        std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit = verList.begin();
        input->vit = vit;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                HANDLE hThread[i] = createThread(0,0,&thread_fun,&input,0,NULL);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(100,hThread,TRUE,INFINITE);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
               CloseHandle(hThread[i]);
}
msmoother.computeEnergy();     // compute harmonic energy based on edge weights
}
```

In thread_fun, i am calling a method on msmoother object in order to update msmoother object with edge weights as well as dstMesh. dstMesh is updated perfectly with thread function. In order to perform computeEnergy on msmoother object, object should be returned to main thread or its state should be persisted. But it returns energy as '0'. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Memory is shared between threads, so all modification they make on shared data eventually become visible without any additional effort (to *return* or *persist* something).

Your problem is, apparently, that you don't *wait* for threads to complete before attempting to use data they should have prepared. As you already have an array of thread handles, `WaitForMultipleObjects` should be a convenient way to wait for all threads' completion (notice `bWaitAll` parameter). Note that [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can't wait for more than 64 objects at once, so you need two calls if you have 100 threads.

Comment: Beat me by 14 seconds... oh SO why do you move so quickly. Upvoting yours since I forgot to mention the limit of 100 objects.

Comment: Actually i called WaitForMultipleObjects and CloseHandle methods before i am calling computeEnergy method. I updated the code.

Comment: @Hello you did not check for errors, and there surely *is* an error with more than 64 (or is it 63?) objects per wait.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I put bWaitAll parameter to TRUE. Then, i decreased thread count to 50. Still i got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If computeEnergy() requires all threads to have completed you can pass the handle to each thread to a [WaitForMultipleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which supports waiting for threads to complete. Within each thread you can add or modify a value within the `msmoother` object (as passed by pointer to `thread_fun`).

The `msmoother` object will live until the threads all return so passing a pointer to it is acceptable.

Comment: Actually i called WaitForMultipleObjects and CloseHandle methods before i am calling computeEnergy method. I updated the code. As per your answer, what i understood is the object will be persisted on main thread after returning from worker threads? But why it is not computing energy?

Comment: @Hello Are you actually updating the DataStructure? You are passing a pointer to a pointer in your call to `createThread`. You may be modifying a different set of memory on accident.

Comment: I updated the code for Data structure and Thread function. Please check it

Comment: @Hello, yes as I suspected you are not dereferencing the pointer to a pointer. So currently you are modifying undefined memory. It may crash at anytime or corrupt your program. Modify this line `HANDLE hThread[i] = createThread(0,0,&thread_fun,&input,0,NULL);` and simply replace `&input` with `input` since input is already a pointer.